# How to Use InAppWebView in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies

I am using inappwebview package in my Flutter app. How can I use to download and upload files in Flutter

I have used the official webview package but it does not support download and upload

Answer (score 0):

Please try this link

[InAppWebView: The Real Power of WebViews in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/inappwebview-the-real-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-c6d52374209d)

Comment: I am getting this error everytime "fatal error: could not find callback". And then the app crashes

Comment: please post your code & your error log

Comment: I/WM-WorkerWrapper( 2893): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=f45423dd-617a-43e9-8e76-f690af9bb9c9, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
I/flutter ( 2893): fatal error: could not find callback
F/libc    ( 2893): FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7315547f30)
E/libEGL  ( 2893): validate_display:87 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/chatty  ( 2893): uid=10514(com.example.untitled1) 3.ui identical 13 lines
E/libEGL  ( 2893): validate_display:87 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: onDownloadStartRequest: (controller, url) async {
            print("onDownloadStart $url");
            print(url.toString());
            final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
              url: url.toString(),
              savedDir: (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path,
              showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
              openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
            );
          },

Comment: @Vkkybliz post your code with your question & add screenshots in the post. you check how to post questions on stackoverflow. It is harder to find problems like from commenting the whole error log.